# Sum of two functions with minimum at 1/2

Tags: functions

I am looking for two positive functions f and g such that their sum h=f+g has minimum at 1/2 and maximum values at 0 and 1. The function h is strictly decreasing between 0 and 1/2 and strictly increasing from 1/2 to 1.

What candidate functions do exit?

I'm looking for specific functions f and g.

Comment: Are you somehow trying to qualify the set of all candidate function pairs? If not this is a bit of a boring question, I think.

Comment: Find a function $f$ with a minimum at $\frac 12$, and take $g = 0$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom See the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can guess that Cosine function has this type of properties. So we can construct such function. as $f(x)=\frac{\cos(2\pi x)}{2}$ and take $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}$. But since you want positive functions so $f(x)=g(x)=\frac{\cos^2(\pi x)}{2}$ would be alright..

Comment: Nice, but I prefer non constant functions f and g.

Comment: what about $f(x)=g(x)=\frac{cos^2(\pi x)}{2}$

Comment: Can you plot it?

Comment: you can check in this [site.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)